# Maximum number of iterations must be positive ERROR when using Logistic Regression (python)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

```
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = 
    sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, 
    shuffle=False)
    return(x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test)

    logisticR = LogisticRegression(random_state=0, max_iter = '800', 
    solver='saga', multi_class='multinomial')
    logisticR.fit(x_train, encoded_ytrain)

    acc = logisticR.score(x_test, encoded_ytest)
    print(acc)
```

When run it gives the following Error: ValueError: Maximum number of iteration must be positive; got (max_iter='800')

As max_iter is 100 by default, is there another way to change the size of iteration?

Comment: One thing that I've thought about is that my data consists of 673 rows. Testsize being around 10-30% would yield a test_size number with decimals and not of integers. Could this have an impact?

Comment: Please do not use the comments space for this kind of additional info - edit & update your question instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the `max_iter` should be an `int`, it should not be a `str`

Can you try the following:

```
logisticR = LogisticRegression(random_state=0, max_iter=800, 
    solver='saga', multi_class='multinomial')
```

Comment: Hey, as i mentioned above, i changed this and am now getting this:

ConvergenceWarning: The max_iter was reached which means the coef_ did not converge
  "the coef_ did not converge", ConvergenceWarning)

Comment: @user3697903 this is a completely different issue (and a warning, not an error). Since the answer resolved the particular issue you reported in your question, kindly accept it and open a new question for the new issue. Please do not use comments for follow-up questions...

Answer (score 0):

Why have you put your max_iter object value inside a ''. You are creating a Str. You need to feed an int. Just put it equal to 800.

Comment: Ah, stupid of me. I changed it and now im getting:

ConvergenceWarning: The max_iter was reached which means the coef_ did not converge
  "the coef_ did not converge", ConvergenceWarning)